# how do plot with the origin on the top-left?

Tags: gnuplot

The origin (point of 0,0) in gnuplot is always located on the bottom left corner with upward incrementing y value.

Is there a way to modify the orientation of the origin to top-left with y-axis incrementing from top to bottom like the coordinate system popularly used in imagings? I am using gnuplot to plot data file.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple. Use

```
set yrange[xmax:0]
```

then you should have the y-axis going from xmax up to 0. On one of my computers I saw that the x-axis was also reversed after this command. If this happens to you as well make sure to get the latest version of gnuplot.

Comment: Hi Azrael, it works but my solution requiring hard-coding the xmax value explicitly. Is there a way to fit the graph without any hard-coding? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I don't know of any way to do that.

Answer (score 10):

This might be what you are actually looking for:

```
set yrange [:] reverse
```